# Geary mail is not logging in my Gmail account

Tags: release-freya

When I am trying to sign in my Gmail with existing Geary mail in Freya.  It's failed to login.  And I don't know the problem.  But the username and password both are right.

Comment: please ask new question, you have changed total meaning of post.

Comment: @Ravan don't vote it down.  I Will ask it tomorrow.  It's too late for me. Anyhow I will accept your answer.

Comment: I retracted my DV :)

Comment: Do you want me to add any information in my answer?

Comment: I dont have idea to integrate email client apps with Freya now. If I need, I will ask a new question.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The simple workaround would be:

- Loginto your gmail account
- Click on the link : [Enable access for less secure apps](https://www.google.com/settings/security/lesssecureapps)
- Turn ON

  Now login to geary. It will work now.

> Don't get panic with the word "less secure"

See [Gmail: Geary doesn't meet modern security standards](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/a/2031/2708)

Comment: Is it less secure to use.?

Comment: idk, but gmail not even allow me to login to thunderbird  :|

Comment: I have logged into my account from geary, but can't post screenshot atm, that is up to you log in or not :)

Comment: So can't use it like popular email clients

Comment: "popular"? see [here](http://www.itworld.com/article/2875981/the-5-best-open-source-email-clients-for-linux.html#slide5), geary  is in top 5

Comment: Alright. But I don't think to use these two apps. (Geary and Thunderbird). Any other apps you know secured one

Comment: @Akelya I think the edit might be useful for better understanding :)

Comment: @Akelya nope, your post totally changed from previous one, I said my post edited with reason.

Comment: thanks, i forgot about it, and now, i can logedin normally

Answer (score 7):

First, use two-factor authorization for your Google account.  This will require you to have your phone each time you want to sign in to Google, but it's a really good idea to be vigilant about your Google credentials.

Next, you'll notice that because you have set up two-factor authorization, you won't be able to drop the security level in the link above.  Instead, set up an app password for Geary.

https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/185833

Comment: That's nice. but i have to kept my mobile along with me, whenever i open Geary. its not usual. even the device is owned by me,eventhough i have to undergo more levels to login. That's really hassle

Comment: This worked fine for me, cheers

Comment: I understand why you phrased it this way, but saying "hey, do this thing," and then "and by the way, here's how you can fix the problem caused by this thing" is a bit... unhelpful? I'd say something like "If you've enabled two factor authorization (which is a good idea because..."