# can't get into my mail even with right password

Tags: pantheon-mail

to whom it may concern,
my mail has been asking to authenticate every time and I do but it wont let me in even with the correct password.
it works on my phone but not my laptop.
what do i need to do please?
thank you in advance
Christina Smith
phone since I can't get into my email 1-619-832-6756

Comment: This will need more information to help solve. Who is your email provider? And do you have 2 factor authentication set on your email account?

Answer (score 1):

For Gmail, you might have to get an "App Password". You can get this by going to

"Manage your Google account" > "Security" > "Signing in to Google" > "App Password"

Finally, use the password they provide to login to your account instead of you regular password.

Answer (score 0):

This may be due to security level of your email app not being considered high enough by your email provider (such as Gmail). If that is the case, you may want to try to solve this issue using the strategies described [here](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/3127/geary-mail-is-not-logging-in-my-gmail-account).