# Mail (Geary): doesn't remember password, can't delete emails and can't start it with "--hidden"

Tags: release-loki, pantheon-mail

I have three differents problems with Mail app (in loki):

1. **Keep asking the password even if "Remember password" is enabled**. (I'm using gmail). Mail remembers the password but keep asking it.
2. **Can't delete emails.** When I press the trash icon or "Supr" nothing happens.
3. **"pantheon-mail --hidden" doesn't work**. I would like to keep it in background mode when I start my computer but it doesn't work. The app starts asking the password (maybe it's the same problem).

I'm very worried about the second problem. I don't think it's a general bug because nobody have posted it in Launchpad.

Could you help me? :)

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2):

You may need to [enable "less secure" apps](https://www.google.com/settings/security/lesssecureapps) in your Gmail settings. See [this answer](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/a/2031/792) and [Google Accounts Help](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/6010255?hl=en) for more details.

I wouldn't be surprised if a future elementary OS release added Google OAuth login to online accounts, which would prevent users from having to do this. (That's of course 100% speculation, but I still hope it happens! )

Answer (score 0):

Go to system-setting>online-accounts and add your e-mail adress accounts. Allow System and Correio options. Open the mail again and check if works.